# Avoid refreshing and saving token multiple times in a cache during parallel https calls to service

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am currently in the process of replacing the blocking HTTP calls from one of my projects with Asynchronous/reactive calls. The `saveOrderToExternalAPI` is an example of the refactor I have done that replaced the blocking HTTP call and now using reactive `WebClient`.

The function `saveOrderToExternalAPI` calls an endpoint and returns an empty MONO in case of success. It also retries when the API returns `401 Unauthorized` error which happens when the token is expired. If you notice the `retryWith` logic, you will see the code is renewing the token (`tokenProvider.renewToken()`) before actually retrying.

The `tokenProvider.renewToken()` for now is a blocking call that fetches a new token from another endpoint and saves it to a Cache so that we don't have to renew the token again and subsequent calls can just reuse it. Whereas the `tokenProvider.loadCachedToken()` function check and return `token` if it is not `Null`, otherwise renew and then return it.

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> saveOrderToExternalAPI(Order order) {
    log.info("Sending request to save data.");
    return webclient.post()
                    .uri("/order")
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(tokenProvider.loadCachedToken()))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(order)
                    .retrieve()
                    .toBodilessEntity()
                    .doOnError(WebClientResponseException.class, logHttp4xx)
                    .retryWhen(unAuthorizedRetrySpec())
                    .doOnNext(responseEntity -> log.debug("Response status code: {}",
                                                          responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue()));
}

private RetryBackoffSpec unAuthorizedRetrySpec() {
    return Retry.fixedDelay(1, Duration.ZERO)
                .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> log.info("Renew token before retrying."))
                .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> tokenProvider.renewToken())
                .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException.Unauthorized)
                .onRetryExhaustedThrow(propagateException);
}

private final Consumer<WebClientResponseException> logHttp4xx = e -> {
    if (e.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError() && !e.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)) {
        log.error("Request failed with message: {}", e.getMessage());
        log.error("Body: {}", e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
}


// -------- tokenProvider service

public String loadCachedToken() {
    if (token == null) {
        renewToken();
    }
    return token;
}
```

Everything is working fine because for now, the `saveOrderToExternalAPI` is eventually doing a blocking call in the Service layer.

```
for (ShipmentRequest order: listOfOrders) {
       orderHttpClient.saveOrderToExternalAPI(order).block();
}
```

But, I would like this to be changed and refactor the service layer. I am wondering would happen if I keep using the existing logic of token renewal and process the `saveOrderToExternalAPI` parallelly as below.

```
List<Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>> postedOrdersMono = listOfOrders.stream()
    .map(orderHttpClient::saveOrderToExternalAPI)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Mono.when(postedOrdersMono).block();
```

Now the calls will be done parallelly and the threads would try to update `token` cache at the same time (in case of 401 unauthorized) even though updating it once is enough. I am really new to reactive and would like to know if there's any callback or configuration that can fix this issue?